# How to deny access of unauthorized users or show them appropriate message when they access urls of django.contrib.auth manually?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm making an user authentication app using Django authentication framework. I'm using provided views like `LoginView` and other views (`from django.contrib.auth`). Problem is when users (authenticated or anonymous) access urls:

```
path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

they see the these pages. for example the page that confirms that a link to reset their password has been sent to their email. while the user is already signed in and they didn't ask for password reset and there is no email send to their email because they never asked to reset their password. they just manually accessed email has been sent confirmation page `127.0.0.1:8000/account/password_reset/done/`.
How to prevent them from accessing these urls or show them appropriate message?

Comment: You may need to override those built in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UserPassesTestMixin which can be imported from

> from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

then you can inherit the method you want to override in views, 
for ex.

> from django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

after inheriting the view you can perform the thing you want to do in test function

class ClassName(UserPassesTestMixin, PasswordResetView):

```
def test_func(self):
    # do your thing
```

Answer (score 1):

For such cases, you need to generate a unique request no and send it through query params e.g. `127.0.0.1:8000/account/password_reset/done?req_no=XXXXXXXX` or just add a lookup field in URL e.g.

```
path('password_reset/done/<int:req_no> or <str:req_no>', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
```

now you can get request no. in view, check if such request no exist if so send the templet for success message else redirect to home page or send 404 or anything you like,

to store the request no. you should create a new model and after sending the success templet, delete that req no from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answers i came up with this solution. (you can use value of `was_sent` to decide whatever). But as i'm new and have low experience there are major doubts about the practicality of this solution. comments are appreciated. (most of the code is copied from the source. added lines are marked with #)

```
class CustomPasswordResetDoneView(PasswordResetDoneView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.request.session['was_sent'] = False #
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['was_sent'] = self.request.session.get('was_sent', False) #
        return context


class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session.get('was_sent', False) #
        self.request.session['was_sent'] = False #
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session['was_sent'] = True #
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['was_sent'] = self.request.session['was_sent'] #
        return context
```